# How to type accent grave without letter or alt in terminal?

Tags: command-line, updates, keyboard, update-manager, keyboard-layout

I'm trying to type a terminal command that calls for an "accent grave" (`) character. I'm running Ubuntu with a US keyboard, and I can't find how to type this. I see lots of talk about using alt codes with num lock on, but I've never done that and can't seem to get that trick to work at all. I'd rather not do that anyway, if there's any more direct way to do it. Any suggestions?

The string I'm trying to type is

```
dpkg -l linux-* | awk '/^ii/{ print $2}' | grep -v -e `uname -r | cut -f1,2 -d"-"` | grep -e [0-9] | grep -E "(image|headers)" | xargs sudo apt-get -y purge
```

It's a suggestion for removing old kernels from /boot. I ran out of space for updates, and though I plan to try to enlarge /boot, I figure this is good to do anyway.

Or is there another character on a US keyboard that will function as a substitute for the accent grave? I confess I don't really understand the command, I'm just trying to replicate the string and see if it works for me.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Wouldn't recommend that command as it can also pick future versions of the kernel if you haven't rebooted since installing them (thus cascade-removing meta-packages like linux-image, etc). `sudo apt-get autoremove` should be enough for 14.04+ installs.

Comment: US or US International? In either case, what does the key above Tab (or the one before 1) show?

Answer (score 1):

The key you're looking for is sitting on the number row on my keyboard:

- Left of <kbd>1</kbd>
- Above <kbd>Tab</kbd>
- Under <kbd>Escape</kbd>

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Waddayaknow. I thought I looked everywhere, I never used that key before. Yes I have it. Good to know for the future.

In the mean time I found out I could use Ubuntu Tweak to remove my old kernels. I did that and the install worked.

Solved. Thanks both of you.